# MS-Access RANK() function

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in Access like this:

```
ID |  Op_ID  
1  |  1  
1  |  2  
2  |  3  
3  |  4  
3  |  5  
3  |  6
```

Is there a SELECT query that I can run in Access that would give me something like this?:

```
ID |  Count(ID)  
1  |  1  
1  |  2  
2  |  1  
3  |  1  
3  |  2  
3  |  3
```

So basically I want a Count of ID that loops over ID every time ID changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query simulates a RANK() function.

```
SELECT T1.ID, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM YOUR_TABLE T2 
               WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.OP_ID >= T2.OP_ID) AS Rank 
FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
ORDER BY ID, OP_ID
```

It works only if there is an unique ID field that allow to count records where:

```
T1.OP_ID >= T2.OP_ID
```

[image]

Comment: Just what i needed!